# KeyEventTranslations.tr doesn't takes effect

Tags: front-end, keyboard

I'm using Mathematica 12.3 on MacOS 10.15, and trying to add new shortcuts to the KeyEventTranslations.tr. I have tried the following two locations:

`/Users/name/Library/Mathematica/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/Macintosh` and `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/Macintosh`,

where the in the former location I have to create a new `KeyEventTranslations.tr`, while there was already such file in the latter location and I modified it.

However,  neither of the files has any effect; in fact, I deleted both files and Mathematica works like usual.

I wonder where to properly add new shortcuts? (I did the same thing in Windows on with the same version of Mathematica, there the shortcut works)

Comment: You can try each subfolder which contains the same file.

Comment: And I think it's still a question: Is it due to a wrong file path?

Comment: @rnotlnglgq I'm not sure; in fact, I don't know how to tell if the path is right or wrong. I essentially followed the instruction of some old post, which said one should "replicate the exact path" from the installation folder to the user folder.

Comment: My experience is: the one in the user folder has no effect. And you'd better paste your modification here.